# Receive Gstreamer stream on remote server, and save to disk

Tags: c++, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have experience using Gstreamer to encode & save video locally, but I am struggling to figure out how to properly have a client computer encode & stream video to a remote sever, which will then save the video in the cloud.

Don't know anything about client's network, so UDP could potentially be blocked. I assume that RTSP is the way to go?

I am aware of `gst-rtsp-server` and came across [test-record](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-record.c), but how does one get at the already-encoded stream data sent from the client so that it may be saved to disk? Is this a good approach anyway?

Comment: RTSP is a protocol to establish a UDP connection (usually). But if you don't require to follow a standard protocol GStreamer offers its own tcp client/server elements for such use case.

Comment: You can send the stream data (RTP) over the TCP connection used for RTSP (interleaved) via `rtsp-client-sink protocols=tcp location=rtsp://...` or `rtsp-client-sink  location=rtspt://...` (notice the extra 't').

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gst-rtsp-server` to send RTSP stream from the server side. You can use the code from this [link](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c) for server.

On the client side, you can use the below pipeline to save the stream into a file. Here I am using mp4mux, but you can use any muxer you want.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp_url drop-on-latency=true use-pipeline-clock=true do-retransmission=false latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=media.mp4
```